# how to plot an image on a specific coordinates in the graph using Plots.jl

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I am using Plots.jl with the plotly backend and I am wondering if it's possible to plot an image at specific coordinates. Say for example I have an image that I want to plot at (x = 1 , y = 1) and the size of the picture of 1. Is it possible to that using Plots.jl?

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use Plots nad Images

```
using Plots, Images

img = load("image.png")

plot([1,2],[1,2],reverse(img, dims = 1), yflip = false, aspect_ratio = :none)
```